# SQL Server 2005: Multiple INNER JOIN expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join, inner-join

I'm having trouble with joining several tables to a main table. My first join is a LEFT OUTER JOIN, and it simply puts two tables together for 2 halves of a whole view (why they split the table has something to do with security). I've got several items on the main table stored as IDs, such as product_id, application_id, state_id and retailer_id. The names of each of these are stored on their own tables, as expected.

My statement works fine with the LEFT OUTER JOIN and **2** INNER JOINs, however the statement stops returning data at **3** INNER JOINs. I don't know if there is a problem with how I've formed my INNER JOINs or what:

```
FROM ((((MyDbo.warranty w
    INNER JOIN MyDbo.products p1 ON w.product_id = p1.product_id)
    INNER JOIN MyDbo.applications ap1 ON w.application_id = ap1.application_id)
    INNER JOIN MyDbo.retailers r1 ON w.retailer_id = r1.retailer_id)
    INNER JOIN MyDbo.states s1 ON w.state_id = s1.state_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MyDbo.warranty_info i on w.warranty_id = i.warranty_id
```

Am I way off base here?

Comment: why all the parentheses?, Can we have all your statement, starting with the `FROM`?

Comment: Sorry, my select statement is extremely complex and is concatenated through several conditions and loops in the VB code.  In addition there are several revealing object names I would need to edit out.  I had the statement working until I added the INNER JOINs, so I'm thinking it's my use of the term that is in correct or the way I formed it.  I though parentheses would help me organize the statement,  but it appears they're pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `INNER JOIN` prevents you from getting records back, then you have an issue with the `JOIN` condition.

The best way to test for this is to use `LEFT JOIN` then a `WHERE` clause looking for `NULL` in the right table, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.key = t2.key
WHERE t2.key IS NULL
```

alternately you can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                  FROM Table2 t2
                  WHERE t2.key = t1.key)
```

Comment: Well, I know that in my main table (guess that's what you mean by right?) I've got nulls. However, I have a CASE in my SELECT that pulls w.state_other when w.state_id is NULL.  So, if that column has NULLs, should I permanently use a LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: It's not just for `NULL`, though.  If you have a join key where you have rows that won't match (`NULL` on right but not on left, for instance) and you want those rows, you **MUST** use `LEFT JOIN` - `INNER JOIN` eliminates those entirely from the result set, that is the purpose.

Comment: That makes complete sense.  My thinking was that if I had a condition not to pull the NULL or non-matched results and instead go to another column for that result, then it would eliminate the need for LEFT.  Now I understand the results are filtered before the columns are selected. Thanks a bunch, it's working now.